# Inserting list into sqlite table column python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I've been looking for an answer online and none seem to fix my issue. I'm getting the following error:

```
line 17, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO semesters (semester) VALUES (?)',mystuff)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current 
  statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

I've made a lot of changes in many places but i still keep getting either this error, another error, or it works, but it won't insert data properly.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('scheduler.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS semesters''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE semesters
                   (idse INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, semester TEXT, Idc INTEGER)''')
                     #FOREIGN KEY (Idc) REFERENCES careers (idc)

mystuff = [('Semester 1'),
           ('Semester 2'),
           ("Semester 3"),]

c.execute('INSERT INTO semesters (semester) VALUES (?)',mystuff)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What about `'INSERT INTO semesters (semester) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'` ?

Comment: Just tried it, won't work. I'm telling it to explicitly insert into column named semester, i think that's why i can only use one '?' because it is only one column.

Comment: Damn'it! What was I looking at :D . You need 3 distinct `INSERT` statements since you want 3 records in fact.

Comment: Would you mind doing an example? And if it works i can pick you as accepted answer:p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [python sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) suggests, use the non-standard shortcut `sqlite3.Connection.executemany()` instead of just `execute()`:

```
mystuff = [('Semester 1'),
           ('Semester 2'),
           ("Semester 3"),]

c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?)', mystuff)
conn.commit()
```